# PHP INPUTS button trying to add it

Tags: php, html, button, output

trying to add the inputs into the output. can you help me with the issue? i feel that the solution is quite simple but idk how to fix it. the output is not showing at all

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="PRACTICE.php" method="post">
        <label>Enter a number</label><br>
        <input type="number" name="first_number"><br>
        <input type="number" name="second_number"><br>
        <input type="number" name="third_number"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Compute">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $total = $_POST["first_number" + "second_number" + "third_number"];
    echo "The computed amount is {$total}";
?>
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for `$total = $_POST["first_number"] + $_POST["second_number"] + $_POST["third_number"];`?

Comment: If you mean you got a completely blank screen, then enable php error reporting in case of a exception. If that's not what you meant, then in future try to provide a clearer problem description. Anyway the comment above should sort you out this time

Comment: you guys got it man, idk how to upvote you but you got it. Thanks